# "When they had made themselves comfortable, a stranger appeared looking very angry." Why 'looking'?

Tags: participle-clauses

> When they had made themselves comfortable, a stranger appeared looking very angry.

May you help me why it uses *looking* in the sentence?

1. Why not use 'looked'?
2. How to comprehend the word 'looking'?

Comment: "looking very angry" is a present participle phrase and probably works as a complement I think.

Comment: Why not use 'looked'?

Comment: It's because it's not passive, as the answer below pointed out.

Comment: Why it is not passive? @dan

Comment: Considering "a stranger looks very angry" or "you look good".  These are active voice.

Comment: Okay, I know now.@dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the cited example, ***looking very angry*** is a [*participle clause*](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/intermediate-grammar/participle-clauses) - a type of *adverbial clause* based on a continuous *(**-ing**)* or past tense *(**-ed**)* verb form.

That link above gives the following useful example of the difference between a *present participle* *(**-ing**)* form and a *past participle* *(**-ed**)* form...

> 1: *Shouting loudly, Peter walked home.* [Peter was shouting]
>    2: *Shouted at loudly, Peter walked home.* [Someone was shouting at Peter]

...where in example #2 the participial verb is *passive*. But I can't see any way to "passivize" OP's exact example using the past participle ***looked***. It just doesn't work. But I *can* offer this contrasting pair if it helps...

> 3: *The stranger sat down, watching closely* [The stranger was the one paying attention]
>    4: *The stranger sat down, watched closely* [Unnamed others were watching the stranger]

Comment: Can you tell me what the meaning of the word 'OP's' is?

Comment: That would be ***you*** - the "Original Poster" (the person who posted the question). In other contexts on SE ("Stack Exchange") sites we use the abbreviation to refer to "Original Post" (the question itself). As you can probably imagine, we often need to refer to these, so the abbreviations are often used by people who have been here a long time.

Comment: Hello, I want to express that: **When they had made themselves comfortable, a stranger appeared looking very angry.** should be used **looked**, for I imagine that **When they had made themselves comfortable, a stranger appeared *who I looked was very angry.*.**

Comment: And what you talked about is verb, but **look** is not only a verb, is but also a conjunctive verb. May you help analysis the sentence again?

Comment: In your context, *appeared* = *came, arrived*. And in *He arrived, **looking angry***, the highlighted continuous participle is an ***adverbial*** element defining ***how*** he arrived *(He arrived **quickly**, He arrived **wearing a suit**, He arrived **late**...)*.